# C# Populate list view from another class

Tags: c#

I have a list view in MainForm but i want to method the code to another class named MaintenanceClass

here is the code in the MainForm to load data into the listview from a text file.

```
List<string> data = File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath + "\\Maintenance\\" + "\\ReportFieldList\\" + "File.txt").ToList();

foreach (string d in data)
{
  string[] items = d.Split(':').Select(a => a.Trim()).ToArray();
  lvFieldList.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(items));
}
```

Here is the method on MaintenanceClass and its giving error that lvFieldList does not exist. lvFieldList is defined on the MainForm

how can i populate the listview in the MainForm using a method in another class named MaintenanceClass?

[image]

Comment: where is this lvFieldList defined

Comment: @Qwerty the lvField is on the MainForm

Comment: Pass the ListView to the method as a parameter. IvFieldList does not exist in that context because of it's scope. You can read up on scopes [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/).

Comment: If you want to have this in another class to separate the read logic from the UI, let the method return e.g. an `IEnumerable<string[]>`, and keep the `lvFieldList.Items.Add(...)` in the MainForm.

Comment: Side note: use Path.Combine to construct a path from it constituents, e.g. `Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Maintenance", "ReportFieldList", "File.txt") `

Comment: thank you for all the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not perform the add item to the ListView in the method reading the file.

Below is the bare minimum for a path to take.

Use an event as shown below.

```
public class FileOperations
{
    public delegate void ProcessLine(string[] sender);
    public event ProcessLine ProcessLineEvent;
    public void ReadFile(string fileName)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            ProcessLineEvent?.Invoke(line.Split(','));
        }
    }
}
```

Call the method in a form

```
var operations = new FileOperations();
operations.ProcessLineEvent += OnProcessLine;
operations.ReadFile("TODO");
```

Add item in this event

```
private static void OnProcessLine(string[] sender)
{
    // add item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Listview items have Text and SubItems
you need to attend the first element of your array to listview item's Text value and the rest will be added as SubItems

```
foreach(string d in data)
{
    string[] items = d.Split(':').Select(a => a.Trim()).ToArray();
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    item.Text=items[0];
    for(int i=1;i<items.Count;i++)
    {
        item.SubItems.Add(items[i]);
    }
    lvFieldList.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this does not help with their problem that `lvFieldList` is not defined here.

Comment: I was assuming he defined it on the designer. Does it have to be defined in coding ? Because I am facing a similar problem

Comment: Yes, probably, but in another class.

Comment: Sorry my bad I haven't read the question properly.